How can I rename a collection to add the total number of vertices and polygon of its mesh objects?
I want to add the total vertex and polygon count of all objects in the collection to the name of the corresponding collection.  How can I do it? I have this script which counts the vertice and polygon counts from oeach object and adds it to the name.

for o in bpy.data.objects:
    if o.type == "MESH":
        m = o.evaluated_get(bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()).to_mesh()
        o.name = str(str(o.name) + "" + str(len(m.vertices)) + " " + str(len(m.polygons)))```


It should be something like this :
import bpy

dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
for c in bpy.data.collections:
    vertices = 0
    polygons = 0
    for o in c.all_objects:
        if o.type == "MESH":
            m = o.evaluated_get(dg).to_mesh()
            vertices += len(m.vertices)
            polygons += len(m.polygons)
    c.name = f"{c.name} {str(vertices} {str(polygons)}"

Iterate over all collections, then parse all mesh objects and add up vertices and polygons. Then rename the collection accordingly.

thank you so much! it works
